# Find the domain $f(x)=\sqrt{\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^2-1}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find the domain $f(x)=\sqrt{\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^2-1}$

My attempt is as follows:

$$\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^2-1\geq0$$
$$\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^2\geq1$$
$$\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Let's assume t as $\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=t$

$$t^2-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\geq0$$
$$t\in\left(-\infty,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] \cup \left[\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\infty\right)$$

But $t\in \left[-1,1\right]$ as $t=\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$. Hence $t\in \left[-1,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right]$

Hence $\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\in \left[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}\right]\cup \left[\pi+\frac{\pi}{4},\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}\right]$ **(this is the principal solution)**

**General solution will be** $\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\in \left[n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4},n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}\right]$

Hence $x\in [n\pi,n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}]$

But actual answer is $x\in \left[2n\pi-\frac{3\pi}{4},2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right] \cup \left[2n\pi,2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Another attempt you can try: Just expand the square initially and see what happens.

Comment: please explain what is wrong here

Comment: I will not answer this, please see once again

Comment: Your answer is correct. The answer you're saying should be true is a subset of your answer, which misses the values $[-\pi+2k\pi,-\frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your answer.  For what it's worth, so does Wolfram|Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28sin%28x%29+%2B+cos%28x%29%29%5E2+-+1+%3E%3D+0

In particular, $\pi$ is in your answer but not in the allegedly correct answer, yet the function is defined at $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\sin^{2}x+\cos^{2}x =1$, so that $$f(x) = \sqrt{2\sin(x)\cos(x)} = \sqrt{sin(2x)}$$

Comment: This is probably a nicer way to solve the problem, but notice that it agrees with the OP's answer.  ($\sin(2x)\geq0$, so $2x\in[0,\pi]+2n\pi=[2n\pi,2n\pi+\pi]$, so $x\in[n\pi,n\pi+\frac\pi2]$.)